# how to get to .error in $httppost in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have this MVC controller post action

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult RunEventService(EventService data){
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
     var resp = new StatusMessages();
     try {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.ServiceName)) {
             resp.success = true;
             resp.Message = string.Format("The service source - {0} has been created successfully", data.ServiceName);
         }
         else {
             resp.success = false;
             resp.Message = "Please enter the name of the service that you want to create.";
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         resp.success = false;
         resp.Message = ex.Message;
         resp.DetailedError = ex.StackTrace;
     }
     return Json(resp);
 }
```

and this status message class

```
public class StatusMessages {
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string DetailedError { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling the http post through this code

```
var url = applicationRoot + "Ad/Service"; 
$http.post(url, JSON.stringify($scope.dataErrorService)).success(function (data) {
    $scope.ServiceMessage = data.Message;
    $(".ServiceMessage").attr("class", "ServiceMessage");
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $(".ServiceMessageError").attr("class", "ServiceMessageError");
});
```

How would my code execute the `.error` section when the `resp.success = false;` is valid? It is always going to the use `.success` method.

I can read the status message in the success and do stuff accordingly, but I want to know what can call the `.error` function.  Am I doing things the correct way?

Comment: in your code it will ever return success, you must check data.success == false according to your class to check if any error happened.

Comment: do you send an error header with the response?

Comment: seem to be misunderstanding that ajax error is not related to error messages you send from server. If you want ajax error to fire you can't return a 200 status and would need to add different status header. `error()` will fire for non 200 status, timout, parsing problems etc

Comment: How do I send a error header with the response??

Comment: set it in your server code ... not hard to google that or read the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a status code in answer from server. 
If code eq 200 (OK), then calls a success method. 
You need to send an error code (500 for example)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for this.

**Example:**

```
var url = applicationRoot + "Ad/Service";

var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.post(url).success(function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
        deferred.reject(response.data);
    else
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
}).error(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
    deferred.reject(error);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: sort of an anti-pattern using `$q` when `$http` itself returns promise